# Bootstrap 4 full-width search bar without navigation break

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, searchbar

Thanks to Bootstrap 4 we can finally and easily without hacks create full-width search bars in the navbar.

Unsing something like this

```
<form class="ml-3 my-auto d-inline w-100">
```

we can create such a beautiful full-width search bar as we can see here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/sbfCXYgqoO

What I still struggle with is multi-word navigation links.

E.g. you can see here at the Stackoverflow navigation the links "Questions" (one word) but also "Developer Jobs" (two words). This is nothing special, but the solution struggles with it.

If you add such a multi-word navigation link to the example provided, the navigation link will break/ force a line break and also the navbar height increases:

https://www.codeply.com/go/BO4QBpaqYD

I would like to force the multi word navigation links to stay in one line and forbid the line break and therefore also keep the navbar height.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks and best

Comment: Thanks, MyStream. Your commend didn't directly help me, but indirectly (which is great, as well): If you add "text-nowrap" to your "<ul>" class like this "<ul class="... text-nowrap"> there will be no line break and it totally works fine. Full example: https://www.codeply.com/go/jctWsJkiae

Answer (score 1):

You are using the class name `w-100` on the form. It sets the width of the form element to `100%`. Therefore, there is not enough place and hence the text breaks.

Use `flex-grow-1` instead to fix the issue. It sets the flex property of the form to `1`.

```html
<form class="mx-2 my-auto d-inline flex-grow-1">
```

Doing so, the `form` takes all the free space inside the nav.

You must use Bootstrap `4.1` since the lower version does not have that class names.

check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vxdzaa)

## Update

You might be tempted to use `text-nowrap` which might fix the issue. But you should not use it because it only prevent text from wrapping and the problem is still there.